# Highlighting and functions

Tags: search, vim, highlight

Let say I have this function in menu.vim:

```
  function! s:Test()
   let search = '\d\+'
   let @/ = search
   return "normal n" 
  endfunction
```

Why doesn't this highlight the search matches?
Only after I do `:set hls` in the commandline it does highlighting.
It does also highlighting when I push the `n` key on my keyboard.
If I put the same line (`:set hls`) in the function it doesn't work.
BTW highlighting is enabled in my VIM.
It highlights fine if I use the commandline.

Comment: Mihai, `:call <SID>Test()<CR>`

Comment: Does it work as you expect it to when the last line of the function is changed to `norm!n`?

Comment: It is strange, since that change works in my setup.  What about changing that `return`-line with `exe "norm!/\r"`?

Comment: ib, no still doesn't work. Curious. Are you sure you haven't `:set hls<CR>` or something like that added after you call the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behaviour might actually be described in the manual under `:help functions-search-undo`, but there is no mention of any workaround.

> The last used search pattern and the redo command "."
>   will not be changed by the function.  This also implies that the effect of
>   `:nohlsearch` is undone when the function returns.

The documentation on `:nohlsearch` also mention this:

> This command doesn't work in an autocommand, because
>   the highlighting state is saved and restored when executing autocommands
>   `autocmd-searchpat`. **Same thing for when invoking a user function.**

Comment: thanks, but I can't imagine that there is no solution. Highlighting is activated when I push the 'n' key on my keyboard. Why can't this  be done? I think there must be a workaround in some way.